# dynamic input til howler via ajax - input not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need some help. I am trying to make howler.js add songs from a directory via ajax, but it is not working.

I am doing a combination of this:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp
https://www.dyclassroom.com/reference-javascript/work-with-audio-in-javascript-using-howler-js

The goal is to get howler to play the first mp3 that is in the folder scanned by php after the first sound has ended. The names in the folder will be random. The problem is that the howler src input does not work! What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script src="howler/src/howler.core.js"></script>

<button id='howler-play'>Play</button>
<button id='howler-pause'>Pause</button>
<button id='howler-stop'>Stop</button>
<button id='howler-volup'>Vol+</button>
<button id='howler-voldown'>Vol-</button>
<button id='txt1' onclick="showHint()">Go</button>

<br><br>
<form action=""> 
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1x" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>

<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

<script>
var filename = '1';
function showHint() {
  var xhttp;

  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;


        var x = this.responseText;
        console.log(this.responseText);

        //x = 'howler/audio/80s_vibe.mp3';
        //console.log(x);

        var howler_example = new Howl({
            src: [x],
            volume: 0.5,
            autoplay: true,
        });

        howler_example.once('load', function(){
            howler_example.play();
        });


    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "gettrack.php", true);
  xhttp.send();   



}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

    var howler_example = new Howl({
        src: ['howler/audio/snap.mp3'],
        volume: 0.5,
        onend: function() {
            console.log('Finished end 1!');
        showHint();

        console.log(filename);

        }
    });

    $("#howler-play").on("click", function(){
        if (howler_example.playing()) {
          //console.log('position 1');
        }
        else {
            howler_example.play();
        }

    });

    $("#howler-pause").on("click", function(){
        howler_example.pause();
    });

    $("#howler-stop").on("click", function(){
        howler_example.stop();
    });

    $("#howler-volup").on("click", function(){
        var vol = howler_example.volume();
        vol += 0.1;
        if (vol > 1) {
            vol = 1;
        }
        howler_example.volume(vol);
    });

    $("#howler-voldown").on("click", function(){
        var vol = howler_example.volume();
        vol -= 0.1;
        if (vol < 0) {
            vol = 0;
        }
        howler_example.volume(vol);
    });

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and PHP file gettrack.php

```
$path = 'howler/audio/';
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
$hint = $files[2];
echo "howler/audio/" . $hint;
```